# Using Geotiffwrite or Worldfilewrite for global TIF in MATLAB?

Tags: coordinate-system, matlab

In MATLAB I have written the code:

```
[image,geo]=geotiffread('africa.tif');
info=geotiffinfo('africa.tif');
geotiffwrite('Wafrica.tif',image,geo);
```

but there was error:

- geotiffwrite>validateR (line 847) The input, R, is a
  map.rasterref.MapCellsReference object indicating that you are
  working in a projected coordinate system. If so, then specify a
  projected coordinate system by setting the appropriate values for the
  'CoordRefSysCode' or 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag' optional parameters.
- geotiffwrite>validateInputs (line 348) R = validateR(R, size(A),
  hasColorMap, type);
- geotiffwrite (line 238) [filename, A, cmap, R, Params] =
  validateInputs(filename, A, cmap, R, Params);

Comment: You should include the description of what you are doing in the body of the question, please don't continue directly on from the title.

Comment: sorry. I want to write a tif to a geotiff.

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/264667/edit) the question, please don't use comments to add detail of what you want to do or try.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:
       [ImageTemp, R] = geotiffread('filename.tif');
       clear ImageTemp;
       info = geotiffinfo(filename);
       geotiffwrite(IMG,outputimage,R,'GeoKeyDirectoryTag',info.GeoTIFFTags.GeoKeyDirectoryTag)

where filename is your image(image base) &
 outputimage is your image that you will want write it with tif format &
IMG is out put  image name

for use geotiffwite on matlab you need to spatial reference detailes for example: datum, projection & ... . this detailes there is on a file with (.tfw) format that is hidden. for get it information we use ( info). I tryed it code and worked for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details. Why does this code work?